# How can I prove that $LXL = I - X$, given $X$ and $I - X$ are positive definite and that $L = (X^{-1} - I)^{1/2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here $A=M^{1/2}$ represents the matrix square root such that it is symmetric and $A^2=M$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Write $X=U^TDU$ where $U$ is orthogonal  and $D$ diagonal, Prove that $L=U^T(D^{-1}-I)^{1/2}U$ by squaring both sides and use this to prove $LX=XL.$